# Android rom file structure and debugging

Tags: java, android, c++, android-source, rom

I have forked a CMod 9 rom to my github. I have all the valid BLOBS and I can build and make changes. Can anyone explain more about what the hierarchy of the files contains? For example what parts make up the kernel? Also, my rom port has volume issues what is the best way to attempt debugging this?

Comment: Your issues should be researched by yourself. See: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Main_Page http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/

Comment: Clarification: What is a good tool/website/community to learn about android rom development.

Comment: Yes I answered your question already in my recent comment. The CM wiki is a good place to start. If it's a unofficial CM rom you can also visit the developers webpage.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of communities that make custom android roms. Just search in Google about this. If you want some basic knowledge how to develop custom modifications then I advice you to watch two parts of [this](http://marakana.com/s/video_tutorial_android_internals_building_a_custom_rom_pt_1_of_2,269/index.html) video.